EDSDK: can’t set 'kEdsPropID_ImageQuality' property
it's successful when i set kEdsPropID_Evf_OutputDevice property
EdsUInt32 device;
    if (err == EDS_ERR_OK)
    {
        // Get the current output device.
        err = EdsGetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_Evf_OutputDevice, 0, sizeof(device), &device);
    }

    if (err == EDS_ERR_OK)
    {
        // Set the PC as the current output device.
        device |= kEdsEvfOutputDevice_PC;

        // Set to the camera.
        err = EdsSetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_Evf_OutputDevice, 0, sizeof(device), &device);
    }

but it's failed when to set kEdsPropID_ImageQuality
if (err == EDS_ERR_OK)
    {
        EdsUInt32 ImageQuality;
        switch (GLOBAL->getCameraImageQuality())
        {
        case 0:
            ImageQuality = EdsImageQuality_SJF;
            break;
        case 1:
            ImageQuality = EdsImageQuality_MJF;
            break;
        case 2:
            ImageQuality = EdsImageQuality_LJF;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        err = EdsSetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_ImageQuality, 0, sizeof(ImageQuality), &ImageQuality);
    }

Is the place I called wrong?

I found the problem!
The camera model I am using does not support the enumeration values passed in the code!
if (err == EDS_ERR_OK)
{
    EdsUInt32 ImageQuality;
    switch (GLOBAL->getCameraImageQuality())
    {
    case 0:
        ImageQuality = EdsImageQuality_S3JF;
        break;
    case 1:
        ImageQuality = EdsImageQuality_S2JF;
        break;
    case 2:
        ImageQuality = EdsImageQuality_S1JF;
        break;
    case 3:
        ImageQuality = EdsImageQuality_MJF;
        break;
    case 4:
        ImageQuality = EdsImageQuality_LJF;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    err = EdsSetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_ImageQuality, 0, sizeof(ImageQuality), &ImageQuality);
}

Just replace it！
